# Interpretation of R2 from PERMANOVA (adonis2) in vegan package

Tags: r, vegan

I am unclear on how the R2 output from adonis2 is interpreted. Is it that a particular factor "explains" the differences in community composition? And thus, would R2 be interpreted as typically is in univariate analyses?

Answer (score 1):

The $R^2$ values reported are indeed coefficients of determination, but they are all partial-$R^2$s (of at least the second-type).  That is to say, the partial $R^2$ values reported most likely will not sum to 100%.  However, each factor can be viewed as explaining (at least) $R^2\times 100\%$ of the variability in the dependent variables.

Comment: The type of R-squared depends on the type of requested test (argument `by` in `adonis2`). In marginal tests they indeed are partial, an do not sum up to 100%. However, the default is to use sequential tests that do sum up to 100%, but the R-squared of individual terms will be order-dependent.